# How to vertically align icon font

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, icon-fonts

I am trying to vertically align font icons. I have tried `vertical-align: middle` but I always get a little align difference. The following example has 2 different ways to use the icons and they are not aligned correctly.

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: yellow;
}

.cart {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cart:before {
  font-family: "fanatic-icons" !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  content: "b";
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/PxvnwqrSXE7pXNDNDqGp4i/icons.css">

<div>
  <span class="icon icon-shopping-cart"></span> Shopping Cart
</div>

<div class="cart">
  Shopping Cart
</div>
```

[image: example]

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block`?

Comment: What kind of iconic font do you use? Please share link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/crphowLg/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `vertical-align: text-bottom` or `vertical-align: text-top`, depending on which one you feel is more vertically centered.

For your shopping cart icon, it seems `text-top` is most vertically centered.

Example at: https://jsfiddle.net/p3g189bg/

Comment: I was trying bottom instead of text-botton. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another nowadays example via Flexbox.

```css
span {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffb0d1;
}

/* target all Font Awesome 5 <svg> tags */
.svg-inline--fa {
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/js/all.js"></script>
<span>
   <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
   Shopping Cart
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for `vertical-align:middle;`

or `line-height:1;`

or using `padding` property you can set icon position

example using `vertical:middle;` property js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vrcarwrj/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `line-height` attribute

You can set it to `0.5,1,1.5` etc

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the above, using the span element method you describe, you could relatively position the span tag, relative to its parent div element.

Like:

```
div{
 position: relative;
}    
span.icon-shopping-cart{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `valign: middle`

and/or then setting the `line-height` to 1px, 1.5px, etc.